# Do I have to perform Hajj if I have done it at the age of 17?

Tags: hajj, obligation

I have performed Hajj at the age of 17 along with my parents. My father paid for the expense. Alhamdulillah Alhamdulillah Allah blessed me with the opportunity to perform Umrah many times after that. I have not done Hajj after that. I am now 47. I want to know if my Hajj at that age of 17 would be considered as the obligatory. I am a male.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [At what age does a person become an adult in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39609/at-what-age-does-a-person-become-an-adult-in-islam)

Answer (score 1):

The age of Hajj depends on your age of being Baligh (mature, means in Islamic context, age when ejaculation starts). 17 is probably an adolescent age, which means your hajj was valid and you do not have to reperform it.

Comment: Baligh(mature, means in Islamic context, age when ejaculation starts)

Comment: Please give your source.

Comment: Source for what? It's elementary Islam: There are 5 conditions of Hajj being obligatory: 1. being Muslim; 2. being of sound mind; 3. being an adult; 4. being free and 5. being able to do it. Looking for a source for that would be like looking for a source for the fact that there are 5 daily prayers, i.e. can be looked up easily.

Answer (score 0):

Performing Hajj (the pilgrimage to Mecca) is one of the five pillars of Islam and is obligatory for those who are physically and financially capable. The age at which a person is required to perform Hajj is not based on a specific number, but rather on reaching the age of maturity and being capable of fulfilling the physical and financial requirements.

If you performed Hajj at the age of 17, and you were physically and financially capable at that time, then you have fulfilled your obligation of Hajj. There is no need to repeat it unless you voluntarily choose to do so.

It is important to note that Hajj is a significant and sacred journey, and it is recommended for individuals to perform it at a time when they are spiritually prepared and can fully benefit from the experience. If you performed Hajj at a young age, it is still beneficial to continue seeking knowledge, deepening your understanding of the rituals, and striving to maintain the spiritual lessons and virtues gained from the pilgrimage.

May Allah accept your Hajj and bless you with continued guidance and spiritual growth.