# How should I pay zakat on this?

Tags: fiqh, zakat

I am a young revert living with her parents. They have some amount of money saved for me for college, but they will not tell me how much it is, nor pay zakat on it if it’s above the nisab. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consdier taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your inquiry: You should wait until it is in your possession as as long as it is not it is the money of non-Muslims who don't need to pay zakat. See also [zakat on savings](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46080/zakat-on-savings).

Comment: IMO your parents own that money, although they intend to spend it on you. If your parents are not Muslim then they do not need to pay Zakat on their money. If they give it to you in the future that is the point from where  you have ownership and then you need to pay Zakat for every year that it is in your possession.

Comment: @UmH would you consider posting an answer?