# What value of stocks to use when calculating zakat?

Tags: fiqh, zakat, hanafi

Salaam alaikum

I have stocks. Let's say the market value today is $100. Do I use this value when calculating zakat? Or do I have to wait until my year end and go based on the market value then?

It is also my understanding that in Hanafi fiqh you can postpone paying zakat on wealth you don't have current access to, like stocks (or a loan). When I do get access, do I pay zakat based on the market value for each year, or market value at the time when I pay zakat?

Comment: I think your inquiry is at least partly covered in [Zakat on savings](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46080/zakat-on-savings/46081#46081).

Comment: I preumse you're referring to the second part of my question? In that case, I'm not sure if my situation applies. I have always had the right to sell/access the stock. It just wasn't liquid, if that makes sense? I have left zakaat unpaid based on discussion with a scholar, but he's busy with family matters right now so I haven't heard back from him on this matter.