# At what age is zakat compulsory?

Tags: practical-islam, zakat

I would like to pay zakat for all my four children.They dont earn.I earn.So how much should I pay for them and is zakat compulsory for them?
2 of my children earn money through freelancing one is 17 and one is 15.

Comment: See also https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9734/13438

Answer (score 2):

You should pay zakat of your money on three conditions, in very short:

1. The money is being held for work / commercial operations. It's ornaments  for women like necklaces , rings... Etc. Or it's your house , of course you don't pay zakat for your house, it's not for your commercial operations
2. It should be more than Nisab, it's a quantity of money, if you have below it you don't have zakat to pay, it's not mandatory. Nisab is what equals 85 grams of  gold. So you should have money that equals one of the quantityies or more.
3. It should be above Nisab for a whole lunar year. (Hijri year). If it goes under the Nisab during the year and then goes above it, you restart counting the year.

How much?

It's 2.5%. and it is calculated at the end of the Hijri year. And shouldn't be delayed much.

Comment: This is wrong. Zakat is a due when two things are satisfied nisab and hawl the age of the person doesn't play any role. .

Comment: That's totally true. Sorry. I've updated it. but I'm sure the first condition should be met. or else people would pay zakat for their houses and must-have things.

Comment: @Medi1Saif The Hanafis differ as according to them Zakat is not due on the wealth of a child.

Comment: @UmH thanks maybe you could post this as an additional answer on the post that is referred to as duplicate. This question has been asked and answered a handful of times.

Answer (score 2):

Zakat is compulsory on the wealth of any (free) Muslim: male, female, adult or child.

The only conditions that play a role are:

Nisab: the minimum amount of the specific wealth that should be at hand for which zakat is a due

Hawl: the time period which this wealth should have been at hand which is one lunar year.